# Finding whether a list contains a particular numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.eye(2)
b = np.array([1,1],[0,1])

my_list = [a, b]
```

`a in my_list` returns `true`, but `b in my_list` returns "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I can get around this by converting the arrays to strings or lists first, but is there a nicer (more Pythonic) way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in numpy the `==` operator returns an array:

```
>>> a == b
array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

You use  [`.array_equal()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)   to compare arrays to a pure boolean value.

```
>>> any(np.array_equal(a, x) for x in my_list)
True
>>> any(np.array_equal(b, x) for x in my_list)
True
>>> any(np.array_equal(np.array([a, a]), x) for x in my_list)
False
>>> any(np.array_equal(np.array([[0,0],[0,0]]), x) for x in my_list)
False
```

Comment: Is the reason why it succeeds if I check the first value (as in `a in my_list` above) due to short-circuiting: if every element in the array is true on the first check it doesn't check the rest of the list?

Comment: @ChrisMidgley: Yes it is short-circuiting (the `any()` function is short-circuiting too, btw). Also, if all elements are True, it is unambiguous that the boolean value is True. But if it's a mix of True and False then NumPy can't decide the implicit conversion, thus raising an Error.

Answer (score -1):

More info about the problem. If you form my_list with

```
my_list = [b,a]
```

the one that fails is a... Interesting problem.

Comment: If you want to know about why, check out the documentation of/google PyObject_RichCompareBool.