# Find index of numpy array in list

Tags: list, python-2.7, numpy

Can someone explain why the following occurs?  My use case is that I have a python list whose elements are all numpy ndarray objects and I need to search through the list to find the index of a particular ndarray obj.

Simplest Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a,b = np.arange(0,5), np.arange(1,6)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> l = list()
>>> l.append(a)
>>> l.append(b)
>>> l.index(a)
0
>>> l.index(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why can `l` find the index of `a`, but not `b`?

Comment: What is going on in this code?

Comment: Generally this error arises when you try to perform a Python boolean operation ('in','if') on a `numpy` boolean array (or list).  e.g. `if [True,False...]:`.  Here I suspect one `index` matches on ids, the other tries an `==` test.  Seems to depend on how the list is constructed.

Comment: List index operations involving `numpy` arrays are probably not a good idea.

Comment: I think @hpaulj, got it right. Python probably tries a `is` comparison first, if that fails python compares with `==`. The latter does not work on numpy arrays and gives you the error. Your code probably only works because the very first `is` comparison is already true and you don't ever invoke a `==` comparison in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Anybody want to make an answer I can accept?

Comment: From the side bar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17703076/901925

Comment: One caveat: if `a` and `b` are different lengths, then no error occurs because `a == b` returns `False` instead of a bool array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applying the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703076/901925 (see the Related sidebare)

```
[np.array_equal(b,x) for x in l].index(True)
```

should be more reliable.  It ensures a correct array to array comparison.

Or `[id(b)==id(x) for x in l].index(True)` if you want to ensure it compares ids.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to convert numpy arrays to lists and transform the problem to finding a list in an other list:

```py
def find_array(list_of_numpy_array,taregt_numpy_array):
   out = [x.tolist() for x in list_of_numpy_array].index(taregt_numpy_array.tolist())
   return out
```